# Connectivity aws → sqlserver AG global listener with dynamic ip

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, sql-server, firewall

Having an app in aws with subnetworks mapped to onprem sqlserver single instance by ip;
After sqlserver migration to 2 nodes AG I need to create rule for aws to access AG global listener which is usually done by netbios name because ip is dynamic dependent on current node (re failover status);

Onprem dns servers are private and cannot be exposed or replicated to the cloud;

What is the best practice to set up cloud app connection string in this case? Any Route 53 routines?

Comment: The question isn't well-worded (maybe for non-English native) so I'm unsure if I understood the problem correctly. You can use 1) NLB to point to your instances then use the NLB name as the endpoint or 2)use Cloud Map discovery service to keep records up-to -date or 3) use lambda to update the records or 4) use VPN to securely expose DNS to certain subnet only or....

Comment: thanks @Putnik! going to try your various options with devops; feel free to format your advise as an answer to be accepted if it will work;

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't well-worded (maybe for non-English native) so I'm unsure if I understood the problem correctly. You can use either:

- NLB to point to your instances then use the NLB name as the endpoint
- Cloud Map discovery service to keep records up-to-date
- lambda to update the records
- VPN to securely expose DNS to certain subnet only
- or...